# Tried to run Corb in windows machine?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I tried running sample corb example by following this [documentation](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Hello-World-from-CORB) . I am having MarkLogic 9 in my machine and for that i had downloaded following jars `marklogic-corb-2.4.0.jar`,`marklogic-xcc-9.0.4` . And created selector.xqy and transform.xqy files as specified in documentaion and kept all these in corb folder.When i tried running it , it is showing Error like below

```
D:\ChromeDownloads\corb\corb>java -cp "marklogic-corb-2.4.0.jar;marklogic-xcc-9.
0.4" -DOPTIONS-FILE=my.properties com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager xcc://adm
in:admin@localhost:9000/CSV-DB
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/marklogic/xcc/exc
eptions/RequestException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.Reques
tException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Is there any other configuration changes need to be done to run CORB ?

Comment: I think you need to use semi-colon (`;`) as classpath separator on Windows. Can you try that?

Comment: @grtjn Tried giving `;` now it is showing another  `ERROR` . Updated in my quesion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is indicating that it cannot find the `com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.RequestException` class, which is bundled in the XCC jar.

Your classpath is not correct and the XCC jar is not available. You forgot the `.jar` file extension when you set the classpath.

```
-cp "marklogic-corb-2.4.0.jar;marklogic-xcc-9.0.4"
```

should be:

```
-cp "marklogic-corb-2.4.0.jar;marklogic-xcc-9.0.4.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks @Hansen, i don't know how i forgot that simple one .

Comment: It always helps to get a second pair of eyes